# How to choose a observation with certain variable are all FALSE?

Tags: r

```
  data.frame = completed  

  unique_ID  Var1  Var2  Var3  
  1000820-1  FALSE FALSE FALSE  
  1000820-2  FALSE FALSE  TRUE  
  1000823-1  FALSE  TRUE FALSE  
  1000823-2  FALSE FALSE  TRUE  
  1000823-3  FALSE FALSE  TRUE  
  1000825-49  TRUE FALSE FALSE  
  1000830-1  FALSE  TRUE FALSE  
  1000830-2  FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

How do I choose those uniqueID with all variables are FALSE ?

I.e output:

```
unique_ID   Var1  Var2  Var3  
1000820-1  FALSE FALSE FALSE  
1000825-49 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: did the answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

One Solution would be this

```
df[rowSums(df[2:4]) == 0,]

unique_ID  Var1  Var2  Var3
1 1000820-1 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

`TRUE`and `FALSE` are counted as `1`and `0`, so `rowSums` gives you the number of `TRUE`.

Alternative with `dplyr`-package:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter_all(all_vars(. != TRUE))

unique_ID  Var1  Var2  Var3
1 1000820-1 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```